# Fast fixed array of dynamically growing vector in Rust

Tags: arrays, memory, vector, rust

I need to create a known number of dynamically growing vectors of integers. The number of the vectors are known (N = 10^7) as well as the maximum size of any of those vectors (M = 2*10^5).

My naive idea was:

```
let list: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![Vec::new(); N];
```

This works but takes ~3s on an i7 2.8 GHz. I've looked into arrays, which generally have 2x performance over vectors:

```
// Does not compile!
let list: [Vec<i32>; N] = [Vec::new(); N];
```

This does not compile as `Vec` is not copyable. I wasn't able to wrap `Vec` with a struct and implement `Copy` on it.

I could use an array of arrays (`[[i32; M]; N]`) but this would allocate way too much memory.

How can I create a list of dynamically sized arrays that performs well?

For comparison, the same in C++ performs under a second:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int32_t>> list(N, std::vector<int32_t>());
```

I was thinking of using a linked list instead of vectors, but I feel there is an elegant solution for this problem.

Update: as @Shepmaster pointed out correctly, compiling with `--release` should be the base of comparison. This way `cargo build --release` provides ~45x speed increase, being twice as fast as clang with `-O3`.

Comment: @Stargateur - Unfortunately that would exceed the memory limit. (That's why I was also considering linked lists.)

Comment: Same: `fatal runtime error: out of memory`

Comment: *performs under a second* — how much under a second? Instantly? I wonder if C++ is deferring some work until later when the vector is actually used, while Rust is being more proactive. If so, then the time difference might be moot as the C++ would take longer later.

Comment: @Shepmaster - yes, I was aware of that effect, so in my example I filled up the whole array and executed the algorithm for my problem - the timing was the partial timing for the allocation - the whole algorithm as well finished in less  than 3s in C++.

Comment: @Stargateur note that a `Vec<i32>` with 2*10^12 entries is 8 TB (7.2TiB). Most people do not have a chunk of RAM that big.

Comment: The dumb question that has to be asked because you didn't state it explicitly: are you compiling and running the Rust code with `--release`?

Comment: @Shepmaster - no, this needs to run on Hackerrank so I tried to keep everything "basic".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148691/discussion-between-itarato-and-shepmaster).

Comment: Checking the assembly, there is no reason for Rust to be slower than C++. Actually, if anything, it seems to me Rust should be faster (at least with Clang, C++ seems to be calling `new` for each inner vector). In release mode of course, because there's little point using C++ or Rust in Debug mode.

Comment: I assume your matrix will be extremely sparse since the full allocation of 10**7*2*10**5*4 bytes is probably not within your budget constraint. If adjacent element placement is not required, you may get away with simply using HashMaps of HashMaps and the array position as keys. You'll pay more in terms of actual memory consumed and slower lookups for individual elements, but if you matrix is truly sparse it may not matter.